# Как выводить полный результат ssh комманд в java используя Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, ssh

У меня в java коде вызываются ssh комманды через Runtime.exec(). Но я не могу полностью вывести результат выполнения команд в реальном времени. К примеру, команда scp ничего не выводит, в том числе прогресс копирования.
Для вывода Error и Input потоков я использую Stream Gobbler.
Помогите, плз, подкорректировать код, чтобы можно было выводить полный результат выполнения ssh комманд в реальном времени.

```
public class FilesUpdate {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    if(runCommand() != true) {
        System.out.println("Aborted!");
        return;
    }
}
private static boolean runCommand(GameSettings gameSettings) {
    String projectDir = '/home/user/projects';
    String[] commands = new String[100];
    commands[0] = "git reset --hard HEAD^ ";
    commands[1] = "git checkout test_branch";
    commands[2] = "git pull origin test_branch";
    commands[3] = "scp -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -P 22 -r user@111.111.111.111:/some/path /some/local/path";
    commands[4] = "git add .";
    commands[5] = "git commit -m 'Comment'";
    commands[6] = "git push origin test_branch";
    try {
        for(int i=0; i<commands.length; i++) {
            if(!commands[i].isEmpty()) {
                if( runCommand(commands[i], projectDir) != true ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
private static boolean runCommand(String cmd, String path) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println(cmd);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null, new File(path));
        InputStream inStream, inErrStream;
        OutputStream outStream;
        inStream = p.getInputStream();
        inErrStream = p.getErrorStream();
        outStream = p.getOutputStream();
        StreamGobbler input = new StreamGobbler(inStream, "OUTPUT");
        input.run();
        StreamGobbler error = new StreamGobbler(inErrStream, "ERROR");
        error.run();
        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //            return false;
        throw e;
    }
    System.out.println(" (command done).");
    return true;
} 
}

class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
InputStream is;
String type;
OutputStream os;

StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
{
    this(is, type, null);
}

StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type, OutputStream redirect)
{
    this.is = is;
    this.type = type;
    this.os = redirect;
}

/** creates readers to handle the text created by the external program
 */
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        if (os != null)
            pw = new PrintWriter(os);

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line=null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (pw != null)
                pw.println(line);
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);
        }
        if (pw != null)
            pw.flush();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

`StreamGobbler` читает стрим в отдельном потоке. его надо запускать через метод `start()`, а не через `run()`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но это не помогает. Результат (прогресс) выполнения scp не отображается ни с run(), ни с start().

Comment: всё правильно, и не будет отображаться. попробуй перенаправь вывод scp в фай и ты получешь пустой файл. такое происходит когда вывод не идёт на терминал с поддержкой ansi кодов

Comment: Но ведь должен быть какой-то способ отображения хода выполнения scp? Если не прогресс с выводом процентов, то хотябы что было скопировано..

Comment: можно попробовать использовать rsync с опцией --progress вместо scp

Comment: twester, спасибо за подсказку! rsync действительно отображает прогресс выполнения в моём контексте!